# Drag and Drop Element Into Textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, textbox, drag-and-drop

In the latest project I'm undertaking, I need to be able to drag a div element from a list and drop it into a textbox. The project itself has a strong messaging component and I'd like to have the functionality to drag contacts from a contact list and place them in a "recipient" textbox containing one or more recipients, comma delimited.

I've figured out dragging and dropping from [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists), but I can't for the life of me figure out a way to populate a textbox by dropping a div item onto it.

I'd appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/2/) that uses jQuery and jQuery UI to achieve what you were looking for. In my example I replace the contents of the text box on drop, but you could easily alter this to append.

Comment: This is exactly what i have been spending hours searching for!!  I am fooling with it, but it does not appear to work in IE? Is it something I am missing?

Comment: Figured it out, for anyone else that stumbles across this post.  I needed to use the latest jQuery files.

Comment: I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/1429/. I am checking to see if the value already exist, if so don't allow it to be added again in the TextArea. But it's not happening for me. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Also, I added the scripts and did the same exact thing in my HTML page but it's not dragging or dropping.